# angular material outlined border input looks deprecated

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular and I am trying to use angular material to show an outline input like this [stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/angular/glempxraxnn?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.ts)
and I have imported `MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule` and angular `FormModule` and this is my html

```
<form action="">
      <div class="white z-depth-2">
        <div class="row center">
          <div class="col m6 s12">
            <p>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
                <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
                <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
              </mat-form-field>
            </p>
          </div>
 <div class="col m6 s12">
                <p>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
                    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
                    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </p>
              </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

but my outline input is looking weird like this :

[image]

am I missing something obvious?

Comment: please provide your code in stackblitz

Comment: @geekymano have you add `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` in `style.css`?

Comment: @Abhishek yes this is the beginning of my style.css

Comment: @geekymano check on this link working your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgml4n

Comment: @geekymano need to `import` this `import {MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` in your app module

Comment: it was because of the style that materializecss was giving to the input